# Comparing multiple content from two tables in aggregation

Tags: mysql, aggregate-functions, group-concat

I have these MySQL tables:

```
mysql> select * from answer;
+----+------------+------------+----------+
| id | questionId | responseId | optionId |
+----+------------+------------+----------+
|  1 |          1 |          1 |        1 |
|  2 |          1 |          2 |        2 |
+----+------------+------------+----------+

mysql> select * from `option`;
+----+-------+------+------------+
| id | label | text | questionId |
+----+-------+------+------------+
|  1 | yes   | Yes  |          1 |
|  2 | no    | No   |          1 |
+----+-------+------+------------+

mysql> select * from rule;
+----+-------+-----------+------------+
| id | label | condition | variableId |
+----+-------+-----------+------------+
|  1 | rule1 | any       |          1 |
|  2 | rule2 | all       |          1 |
|  3 | rule3 | none      |          1 |
+----+-------+-----------+------------+

mysql> select * from rule_options_option;
+--------+----------+
| ruleId | optionId |
+--------+----------+
|      1 |        1 |
|      2 |        1 |
|      3 |        1 |
|      3 |        2 |
+--------+----------+

mysql> select * from variable;
+----+-----------+----------+
| id | label     | surveyId |
+----+-----------+----------+
|  1 | variable1 |        1 |
+----+-----------+----------+
```

And I'm trying to make the output look like this:

```
answerId|optionId|optionLabel|var1             |
--------|--------|-----------|-----------------|
       1|       1|yes        |rule1,rule2      |
       2|       2|no         |rule1            |
```

Based on these rules:

- Rule 1:

  If **any** of the optionIds in `rule_options_option` exists in `answer` the rule is displayed in the column `var1`.
- Rule 2:

  If **all** the optionIds in `rule_options_option` exists in `answer` the rule is displayed in the column `var1`.
- Rule 3:

  If **none** of the optionIds in `rule_options_option` exists in `answer` the rule is displayed in the column `var1`.

I threw this naive implementation together that obviously won't work:

```sql
SELECT a.id as answerId, o.id as optionId, o.label as optionLabel, 
rule1.label as any, rule2.label as `all`, rule3.label as none,
GROUP_CONCAT(IF(v.label = 'variable1', rule1.label, NULL)) as var1
FROM answer a 
LEFT JOIN `option` o ON o.id = a.optionId
LEFT JOIN rule_options_option ro ON ro.optionId = a.optionId
LEFT OUTER JOIN rule ON rule.id = ro.ruleId
LEFT JOIN rule rule1 ON (rule1.condition = 'any' and rule1.id = ANY(SELECT ruleId FROM rule_options_option))
LEFT JOIN rule rule2 ON (rule2.condition = 'all' and rule2.id = ALL(SELECT ruleId FROM rule_options_option))
LEFT JOIN rule rule3 ON (rule3.condition = 'none' and rule3.id != ro.ruleId)
LEFT JOIN variable v ON v.id = rule.variableId
GROUP BY a.id
```

What's a good way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

[Here's a fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/eABYVESARLh2SeJ8ZgeUcE/1).

Comment: For the love of (what's left of) humanity, don't call a table 'option'

Comment: @strawberry lol. Why? Because it's a reserved word?

Comment: I don' get it. for answerid 1 there must apply all rules because rule_options_option; has all three linked, so why are there only Rules1 and 2 aand why yhas answerid 2 Rule 1 instead of Rule 3